# doctrine2 use redis cache layer of zend framework3

Tags: doctrine-orm, redis, zend-framework3

i used doctrine2 in zf3. Now i want to use cache layer with redis, how to do that?

someone can give me some docments or examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Please google about your question :)

Comment: Useless information, the most is zf2.

Comment: You might need to work on your google skills: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/caching.md